# Oracle11g Express Edition SYSTEM schema is locked

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

Recently I installed oracle 11g Express Edition in my windows 7 (64 bit) OS. I have set the password for SYSTEM schema while installing Oracle. I have tried to login SYSTEM schema. But I failed to login because of wrong password. Now the account is locked. I could not find the password as i didn't unlock any other schema.

Please help me to re-set or find the password.

Comment: See this question for how to reset password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740119/default-passwords-of-oracle-11g - generally you shouldn't log in directly as sys or system in recent Oracle versions, but "... as sysdba"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
> sqlplus / as sysdba
sql> alter user system identified by *newpassword* account unlock;
```

Comment: for me `sqlplus / as sysdba` resulted in a TNS Protocol Error. Instead, `sqlplus SYSTEM@PM as sysdba` worked. SYSTEM is the user that was locked out. And PM is a database.

Comment: Thank you Alexadr... I was searching the correct answer for a day.